# Is there a way to "swipe" between lists in Reminders in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, reminders

In prior versions, you could simply swipe to switch between lists.

The default setting in the iOS 6 version has eliminated this gesture, which means that you have to click on the lists icon, then click again on a specific list.

Is there a setting somewhere that lets you turn swiping back on to switch lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the iOS 6 version has swipe-to-delete enabled, you must swipe the list’s title to move between lists. Swiping in the body won’t work.

Comment: That's... exactly the kind of non-obvious, but logical thing I was hoping for.